# Android Phonegap: $.ajax does not fire callback for unauthorized (401)

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using PhoneGap to build an Android app. Using either jQuery or Zepto, I'm able to make calls to the website APIs using the $.ajax call. However, when the website returns a 401 (unauthorized) response, there seems to be no callback from the ajax call - none of "success", "error", or "complete" get called.

Note that the same code works fine when the response is 200 or 500.

I'm using Zepto 1.0rc1 and/or jQuery 1.7.2 with PhoneGap 1.6.1 .

```
function make_base_auth(user, password) {
    var tok = user + ':' + password;
    var hash = btoa(tok);
    return "Basic " + hash;
}

$('#button').on('touchstart', function() {
    console.log("UPLOAD --- ");
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://mywebsite/api/v1.0/test/?ts=' + new Date().getTime(),
        type: 'GET',
        beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth('username', 'password')); 
        },
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
            console.log("AJAX: SUCCESS: " + data);
            $('h1').text("AJAX!!");
        },
        error: function(xhr, errortype, error) {
            console.log("AJAX: FAIL: " + errortype + " - " + error);
            $('h1').text("AJAX FAIL");
        },
        complete: function() {
            console.log("--- Complete");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Downgrade phonegap. Yes. You read that right.

I tried 1.4.1: didn't work.

I tried 1.3.0: works.

So yeah, that's that.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. When I get HTTP 401 back and use

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    timeout: 5000, // Some timeout value that makes sense
    ...
});
```

then the error callback is called with `{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"timeout"}`. In that case you would have to guess that the real error is the HTTP 401.

Alternatively you can use

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    async: false, // :-(
    ...
});
```

and your error callback will get something like `{"readyState":4,"responseText":"<html>...</html>","status":401,"statusText":"Unauthorized"}` back.