# Sencha Touch 2 Ajax Basic Authentication Request Failing on Android

Tags: ajax, webview, cordova, sencha-touch-2, basic-authentication

I have a Sencha Touch 2.2.0 app wrapped in Phonegap/Cordova 2.7.4.  It makes a simple ajax call against a REST API that uses HTTP Basic Authentication.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/test',
    method: 'GET',

    // timeout occurs on invalid credentials?
    timeout: 2000,
    //enable basic authentication
    withCredentials: true,
    // need useDefaultXhrHeader: false and disableCaching: true to get cookies to work.
    useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
    disableCaching: true,

    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    success: function(response) {
        // process JSON data...

    },
    failure: function(response) {

        console.log('Login failed. response.status:' + response.status +
            ', response.statusText:' + response.statusText +
            ', response.responseText:' + response.responseText);

        // invalid credentials appears to timeout...
        // response.status:0, response.statusText:communications failure, response.responseText: undefined
    }
});
```

This code works fine on iOS devices but NOT on Android?

> ... D/CordovaLog( 1967): Login failed. response.status:401,
>   response.statusText:Unauthorized, response.responseText:Unauthorized

If I run this app in the default android browser (hosted on a local apache development web server) then the browser prompts me to enter credentials.  I suspect that the ajax request times out waiting for credentials.  Regardless the credentials are correct and, again, it works on iOS?

Any thoughts?

Comment: This problem maybe related to webview? ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656355/why-my-requests-with-http-basic-auth-get-status-0-when-i-set-bad-credentials-p